# Samba mount fail on cifs

Tags: cifs, samba4

Client `Debian`, server `Windows 2019`.
Even that DNS resolved ok, I added **eagleeye** on /etc/hosts, also modified /etc/samba.smb.conf adding:

```sh
   client min protocol = SMB2
   client max protocol = SMB3
```

I can browse the share with smbclient:

```
#> smbclient  -V
Version 4.2.14-Debian

#> smbclient -L eagleeye -Uuuu%ppp -Wdom
Domain=[DOM] OS=[] Server=[]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
        C$              Disk      Default share
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        ...
        Repo            Disk

#> smbclient  //eagleeye/repo -Uusername%admin -Wdom
Domain=[DOM] OS=[] Server=[]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Thu Aug  1 17:56:27 2019
  ..                                  D        0  Thu Aug  1 17:56:27 2019
  Autodiscover                        D        0  Fri Apr 20 13:30:00 2018
  gitupdate                           D        0  Tue Aug  6 22:45:33 2019
  SharedModules                       D        0  Tue Aug  6 22:47:17 2019
...
...
                26085631 blocks of size 4096. 8936156 blocks available
smb: \>
```

however, I can't mount as a share as

```sh
mount -t cifs //eagleeye/repo ~/share
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //eagleeye/repo,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

#> lsmod | grep cifs
cifs                  546304  0
dns_resolver           12641  1 cifs
fscache                45304  2 nfs,cifs

# adding vers=2.0
#> mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0 //eagleeye/repo ~/share
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //eagleeye/repo,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

#> dmesg | tail -n10
...
[226622.680227] Key type dns_resolver registered
[226622.733361] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[226622.781716] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[226622.828384] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[226622.872472] Unable to determine destination address.
```

Comment: What sounds puzzling in `dmesg` output is `Unable to determine destination address.` Indeed, OTOH name resolution worked with previous commands, but could be something to investigate...

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about Debian, but on CentOS `mount.cifs`uses SMB1 by default, so you must use the `vers` option to force SMB2/3: **`mount -t cifs -o vers=2.0 //eagleeye/repo ~/share`**
Other possible values on CentOS: `2.1`, `3.0`.

Comment: Edited to include vers=2.0 result, however, looks like the switch -o is ignored! any value is accepted

Comment: *Note: despite above comment position, this is the OP that was edited, not the proposed answer*